# SpringBootTest Spring Security InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository NoSuchBeanDefinitionException in Test

Tags: spring, spring-security, autowired, spring-boot-test

I created a custom `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` that is initialized with a `ClientRegistrationRepository` and `String authorizationRequestBaseUri`. It is based on this implementation here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests.

I initialize my custom resolver in my `WebSecurityConfig`.

```
@Autowired
private InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository inMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
        // ...
        .oauth2Login(oAuth2LoginConfigurer -> oAuth2LoginConfigurer
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomtAuthorizationRequestResolver(inMemoryClientRegistrationRepository, "/oauth2/authorization"))
        )
        // ...
}
```

When I run the app, the `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository` is correctly autowired and loads my clients from my *application.yml*.

In my test, I want to have the same `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository` with the clients loaded from my *application.yml*. However, I cannot find a way to inject / autowire the `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository`.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class, InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository.class  },
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class CustomAuthorizationRequestResolverTests {
    @Autowired
    private InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository inMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
    
    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        HttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver = new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(inMemoryClientRegistrationRepository, "/oauth2/authorization");
        
        resolver.resolve(request, "client");
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

With this code I get

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'inMemoryClientRegistrationRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I can only find tests that use `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository` by building it separately in the test and I cannot find any tests that load the clients from the *application.yml*. What do I have to do so that I can use my `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository` with the values from my *application.yml* in my tests?

**Update**

I use the default `TestConfiguration` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.java) and `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.java) classes from `spring-boot-test-2.3.1`.

Comment: can you add the code for `TestConfiguration` and `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer`?

Comment: I updated my answer and added a github link to the code.